# Twig add global array doesn't work

Tags: php, twig

I'm using the following statement in my code:

```
$twig->addGlobal('config', $config);
```

NOTICE: $config is an array.

However, it doesn't work. I always need to include following in my render function:

```
echo $twig->render('example.html.twig', array('config' => $config));
```

Cause, twig seems to be ignoring my addGlobal definition.

Is it a known bug in Twig? I'm using a bit outdated version, cause of Autoloader. The version I use is: 1.20.0

Comment: I'm using 1.18.0 and can verfiy `addGlobal` does work in that version. Are you sure you are calling the `addGlobal` to the correct instance of `twig`?

Comment: It works with normal variables, yes. But not with arrays. Can you test it with arrays? Yes, I'm sure I'm calling it in the correct instance cause in another place I got $twig->addGlobal('template_path', $template_path); and it works. However, it's normal variable not array.

Comment: Works perfect with an array in 1.18.0 [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kTupKfiL)

Comment: You can verify all globals with `<?php foreach($twig->getGlobals() as $key => $value) { ...` though

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. I was defining new values in the array after it has been added to global. I thought it's done with reference, but it's not. Thanks for help @DarkBee